# Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature

Tags: swift, generics

I want to associate function's generic type to other class inside the function.

I  get error `Generic parameter 'T' is not used in function signature` for code below.

```swift
    func someFunc<T: Codable>() {
        let nmyClass = MyClass<T>()
    }
```

How can I make the error go away without returning T?

When I add return T? from the function error goes away but since I don't need to return anything, it is kid of odd.

```swift
    func someFunc<T: Codable>() -> T? {
        let nmyClass = MyClass<T>()
        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally would pass the type here:

```
func someFunc<T: Codable>(for: T.Type) {
    let nmyClass = MyClass<T>()
}
```

You would then call it as:

```
someFunc(for: Int.self)
```

Comment: You can even discard it with `func someFunc<T: Codable>(for _: T.Type)`